# почему ris[q][w] = "*" меняет весь столбик, а не одно значение?

Tags: python

```
n = int(input())
a = int(input())
b = int(input())

ris = [["."] * n] * n
dim = []
for j in range(a,b + 1):
    dim.append(j)
center = [int((((n - 1)/2) + 1)),int((((n - 1)/2) + 1))]



for q in range(n):
    dis = 0
    for w in range(n):
        dis = (abs((w + 1) - center[0])) + (abs((q + 1) - center[1]))
        if dis in dim:
            ris[q][w] = "*"

for e in range(n):
    print(ris[e])
```

Данный код почему-то ris[q][w] = "*" меняет весь столбик, а не одно значение массива.
Вся суть задачи, что он должен закрашивать точки, которые лежат на расстоянии в {dim}, и благодаря этому получается ромб, в отлаживании кода он просто закрашивает весь столб.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

потому что ссылки списков и все такое

когда вы делаете "список * число", то получаете список все элементы которого ссылаются на первоначальный список

сделайте так:

```
ris = [["." for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
```

P.S.

а вообще весь ваш код можно свернуть в:

```
print(*[[".*"[a <= abs(w - (n - 1) // 2) + abs(q - (n - 1) // 2) <= b] for w in range(n)] for q in range(n)], sep='\n')
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное)))

Answer (score 0):

вам надо заменить

```
ris = [["."] * n] * n
```

на:

```
ris = [["."] * n for _ in range(n)]
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!!